# 'function' object has no attribute 'data'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
from sklearn import datasets 
iris=datasets.load_iris
X = iris.data
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-12a2d725131f> in <module>()
----> 1 X = iris.data

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'data

I load iris dataset from sklearn ,but when i write "X = iris.data",an error occur as "AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'data'"
```

Comment: Did you try calling the function?

Answer (score 10):

`load_iris` is a function and needs to be called as such:

```
from sklearn import datasets 
iris=datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `load_iris()` instead of `load_iris`, like this,

```
iris = datasets.load_iris()
```